# how to make rails project available locally with /etc/hosts IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby mine btw running puma. I am trying to make my rails app available on local network. 0.0.0.0:3000 localhost doesn't work. I tried editing the etc/hosts file so that my IP address would pull up <domain.com> locally but it won't work. my IP address itself works to pull up on other computers in network, but t he domain name setting doesn't  in the etc/hosts file. We have a firewall in place. What can I do thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start rails s -b IP
and use this IP in hosts file to acces site by domain.name if you need.

That is all.

Comment: I do that and it doesn't work. IT only works when I type in my IP other computers but not the domain name